# which action must you perform before your application can retrieve the data?

Tags: database, connection

Your application must pull data from a database that resides on a separate server,which action must you perform before your application can retrieve the data?

- Install the database on each client computer
- Configure the network routers to allow database connections
- Establish a connection to database by using appropriate data provider
- Create a routine that bypass firewalls by using windows management instrumentation
- Which one of the above is best suitable answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on my opinion the best suitable answer:

**Configure the network routers to allow database connections**

such as:

> create administrator account for the web server
>   configuration of firewall